# Actionscript 3.0 Microphone Decibel

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, microphone, decibel

Hy,

How can hy obtain decibels value from Microphone class im Actionscript 3.0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only value you can get from Microphone is `activityLevel`. You can't get the rough dB value of your sound source from multiple reasons:

1. Your soundcard may oper a dynamic amplification/compression of the sound, which means a quiet sound may have the same level of a loud one on the output.
2. The response of your microphone is not linear, you must know precisely the curve of its response to get the real volume of your source.
3. Your material is not calibrated, you will get a relative value. You would need a certified sound source to match the value you get to the real amount of dB.

Sorry, cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot :(, so theres no change for i create an app to do that, even if its not in flash?

Comment: Unless you are certain of the microphone you are using and have calibrated it and are certain the soundcard has no dynamic amplication or compression. This could be possible but you won't be able to deploy your application, it will only work on one configuration. Even if you use a low-level language to avoid any OS/material treatment of the sound, you'd still have to deal with the microphone's response.

Comment: (if you are ok with the answer, could you please tick it as valid? thank you ;) )